# How do I solve $af(z)+c \int_{z}^{0} \int_{-h}^{z} f(t)dt^{2}=d $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

How do I solve

> $$af(z)+c \int_{z}^{0} \int_{-h}^{z} f(t)dt^{2}=d $$

while $-h<z<0$ and $a,c,d$ are real constants. I tried to rewrite the equation as
$$a{y}''+cy=d  $$
where,  $y(z)=\int_{z}^{0} \int_{-h}^{z} f(t)dt^{2}$.
However, I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: Might want to adjust your integral: make it clear which $z$ is which, use something different for the variable being integrated over, etc.

Comment: There seems to be a double integral, but only one differential, $dz$, and the variable $z$ also acts as an integration limit.  So, there is probably a typo somewhere.  For example, what sense would you make even of the single integral
$$
\int_{-h}^{z} f(z) \: dz \; ?
$$

Comment: If you care to get assistance you might take care in asking for it.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the integral. I also used a different variable inside the integral.

Comment: Identical to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057332/how-do-i-solve-differential-eq-like-ycy-d from the same user. Why do you post the same question twice?

Comment: That question was closed because of insufficient explanation. what am I supposed to do? should I delete the other one?

Comment: You should *improve* the other one so it gets reopened.